# Retrieve a specific post's featured image and show on a different page

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

What I'm simply trying to do is grab the featured image thumbnail image from a specified post/page and display that image on any other page somewhere.

So for instance, if it's a single post, use the thumbnail from post 9.  If it's this page, use the thumbnail from 82, and so on.

It doesn't seem as simple as this:

```
$thumbnail_id = get_the_post_thumbnail(82);
```

Because I've tried that and it doesn't work in all scenarios.

Is there a universal way to do this?

Comment: What are you expecting the above code to do, exactly? You are loading the thumbnail's HTML into the $thumbnail_id variable, but not echoing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might be the reason why it wasn't working the way I needed.

before -> if ( has_post_thumbnail () )

Seems that only relates to the specific post/page you're on, and not the page/page that you're getting the image from - if you don't enter a post ID.  But then I tried it with the post ID I was trying to retrieve from and it works.

after -> if ( has_post_thumbnail (9) )

Comment: if you [look at the function in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), you'll see that you can pass the post id of the post you want to check. also, you're missing the parens on the function: `if ( has_post_thumbnail() )`.

Answer (score 1):

Each post object has a public member `$post_parent`. That is the post ID of the parent post. So this should work:

```
$thumbnail = '';

if ( ( 'event_posts' == get_post_type()
        || is_page( 'events' )
        || is_page( 'restaurants' )
        || is_page( 'recreation' )
        || is_page( 'entertainment' )
        )
    && ! empty ( $GLOBALS['post']->post_parent )
    )
{
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $GLOBALS['post']->post_parent );
}

echo $thumbnail;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but couldn't get it to work out.  I also revised my question.

Answer (score 0):

method 1)

```
<?php
$target_post_id = '999';
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($target_post_id));
echo '$feat_image';
?>
```

method 2)

```
<?php 
$target_post_id = '999';
if (has_post_thumbnail($target_post_id) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($target_post_id), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<?php echo $image[0]; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?